# Seaweedfs: TTL options for S3 and/or volume

Tags: seaweedfs

I'm really interested in TTL feature for files found in Seaweedfs. The only missing part in my understanding is interaction with S3 and on the volume level.
Currently my app is using S3 libraries to interact with the storage. It writes a lot of small files, which are never rewritten, but being accessed for time to time. Also I need to keep only x days of the written data, while older entries should be removed. Seaweedfs looks like a perfect solution to me. But as far as I understand the docs, I can only set TTL using it's own API.

So here's my two questions:

1. Can I somehow set the TTL for a file using S3 abstraction layer?
2. If not, can I have default TTL value for say per bucket (or volume, I guess) or per cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not. This can be a good feature to add.